# Entity Framework build exits with warnings and will not run tests after cloning the CodePlex repo

Tags: c#, visual-studio, entity-framework, msbuild

I am trying to build EF after following [these instructions](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/documentation). Everything seems to have completed successfully, but when I run build.cmd I get two warnings:

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(1578,5):
>   warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate
>   the assembl y "Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework,
>   Version=10.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a,
>   processorArchitecture=MSIL". Chec k to make sure the assembly exists
>   on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get
>   compilation errors. [C:\Users\Chasemedallion\Documents\entityframework\test\EntityFramework\VBTests\VBTests.vbproj]

and

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(1988,5):
>   warning MSB3283: Cannot find wrapper assembly for type library
>   "EnvDTE". Verify  that (1) the COM component is registered correctly
>   and (2) your target platform is the same as the bitness of the COM
>   component. For example, if the COM component is 32-bit, your target
>   platform must not be 64-bit.
>   [C:\Users\Michael\Documents\Interests\CS\entityframework\src\EntityFramework.PowerShell\EntityFramework.PowerShell.csproj]

After the second warning, the command exits and does not run any tests, even when run with /t:Test. Can anyone give me pointers on what these errors are or how I can resolve them? Strangely, I see neither warning when I build from VS2012 Express (Desktop) with Ctrl+Shift+B.

Also, I've confirmed that Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dll is in C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies.

Comment: Are you running the script from the VS command prompt?

Comment: @Pawel: nope, I'm running it from cmd. Will that make a difference?

Comment: I believe so. VS command prompt has more environment variables and paths defined that may be used. Let me know if it helps. When you build from the VS what project/solution you build? I just wonder if you don't see the warnings when building from VS because you don't build these projects.

Comment: @Pawel: it looks like using the VS command prompt did the trick. If you make your comment an answer I'll accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script needs to be run from the Developer/VS command prompt as it sets environment variables and paths in the way that makes it possible to find files and resolve dependencies.